# Python - NameError when using type hinting

Tags: python

I can see `Unresolved reference 'Segment'` in pycharm but in the video the author and I have the same code and the author doesn't seem to have any error.

If I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Username\anaconda3\python.exe G:/Temp/Python/advanced-oop/flight.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Temp/Python/advanced-oop/flight.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Flight:
  File "G:/Temp/Python/advanced-oop/flight.py", line 5, in Flight
    def __init__(self, segments: List[Segment]):
NameError: name 'Segment' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the complete code:

```
from typing import List


class Flight:
    def __init__(self, segments: List[Segment]):
        self.segments = segments

    @property
    def departure_point(self) -> str:
        return self.segments[0].departure


class Segment:
    def __init__(self, departure, destination):
        self.departure = departure
        self.destination = destination


flight = Flight([Segment('GLA', 'LHR')])
print(flight.departure_point)
```

Here is the screenshot from the video and it executes fine.

[image]

Comment: Class Segment should be defined before using it in type annotation. Move definition of Segment before.

Comment: Put `Segment` before  referenced part

Comment: Okay so how is the author's code working fine? I thought about moving it

Comment: @John Probably it was defined before too somewhere. Or author has some python which accepts any annotation.

Comment: How do you know that it is?  Maybe what the author posted is different than what actually worked for him/her.

Comment: Oh never mind. It seems the author had the error at the end of the video and he moved the code to the top. Since he didn't have any pycharm underlining I thought he had something else going on.

Answer (score 3):

When the line `def __init__(self, segments: List[Segment]):` is interpreted by Python, the class `Segment` has not yet been defined.  Swap the definitions of `Flight` and `Segment`, and the code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Class `Segment` should be defined before as you'll be using it in `Flight` class, specifically in a constructor.

```
class Segment:
    def __init__(self, departure, destination):
        self.departure = departure
        self.destination = destination


class Flight:
    def __init__(self, segments: List[Segment]):
        self.segments = segments

@property
def departure_point(self) -> str:
    return self.segments[0].departure


flight = Flight([Segment('GLA', 'LHR')])
print(flight.departure_point)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot you shared, Segment is unknown object
Basically python doesn't know what is meant by Segment.

To resolve it,

- Cut from line# 20-23 and paste it above `class Flight`

Comment: Nope.  See any of the other three answers.

Answer (score 0):

Move lines 20-23 above the reference in line 12. You are simply referring to the class `Segment` before it is defined.

In my experience python is compiled sequentially (top to bottom) by most interpreters. Meaning you cannot reference a variable on line 1 that is not declared yet until line N. Unlike say Java where you can put variables anywhere as long as they are in scope.

This has the advantage of the code is readable from top to bottom, but is slightly more strict in terms of order of operations.

Comment: `before it is referenced` should be probably changed to `before it is defined`.